# Make clang's Memory Sanitizer report unitialised variable use without it deciding branching

Tags: c++, memory, clang, llvm, address-sanitizer

I was experimenting with Clang 6.0's Memory Sanitizer(MSan). 
Code is compiled with

```
clang++ memsans.cpp -std=c++14 -o memsans -g -fsanitize=memory -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Weverything
```

on Ubuntu 18.04. As per the MSan [documentation](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizer)

> It will tolerate copying of uninitialized memory, and also simple
>   logic and arithmetic operations with it. In general, MemorySanitizer
>   silently tracks the spread of uninitialized data in memory, and
>   reports a warning when a code branch is taken (or not taken) depending
>   on an uninitialized value.

So the following code does not generate any error

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    int x;
};

int main() {
    Test t;
    std::cout << t.x;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this will

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    int x;
};

int main() {
    Test t;
    if(t.x) {
        std::cout << t.x;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally one would like both of these code samples to generate some sort of error since both are "using" an uninitialised variable in the sense that the first one is printing it. This code is a small test code and hence the error in the first code is obvious, however if it were a large codebase with a similar error, MSan would totally miss this. Is there any hack to force MSan to report this type of error as well ?

Comment: Note that some compilers may catch the use of the uninitialized variable: GCC (https://godbolt.org/g/YXk4z1) and MSVC (https://godbolt.org/g/UPmBK6).

Comment: I am a little surprised the first example doesn't generate an error because `itoa()` should require some branch on the data in order to know when to stop. (maybe that's performed in the pre-compiled part of libc++?)

Comment: @Acorn With a tool like a MSan, I am expecting run time debugging, what you suggest is true but it is a compile time check.

Comment: Seems like a bug, you could log it

Comment: @JVApen As per MSan docs, it is not really a bug since no "branching" is taking place in the first code snippet. My main point is regarding MSan.

Comment: @DeepankarArya: Sure, but I am not sure why would you not prefer to catch it earlier.

Comment: I get your point. It's just that it would be convenient to have a single comprehensive tool(MSan) on which one could rely to catch different sorts of errors. Also, I feel a bit more confident with run time checks since I feel compile time checks are a bonus and not that thorough.

Comment: What does "this type of error" mean? Clearly it is something more than the  branching decisions MSan currently reports, and if I understand you correctly you don't want it to include logic and arithemetic.

Comment: Front-loading as much work (including validation) as possible to compile-time is one of the most fundamental aspect of C++. Tools like MSan are good safety nets, but they should never be your primary means of catching errors. (I think your question is still valid though, just replying to your sentiment about compile vs runtime checking)

Comment: yeah. I assume it's a bug then that clang is not giving a warning.

Comment: Are yo sure the code that outputs decimal digits is compiled with msan?

Comment: @arnt yes it is compiled with msan

Comment: Curious. How does the function look?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your C++ library wasn't built with MSan. Unlike ASan and UBSan, MSan requires that the whole program was built with msan enabled. Think of it like having a different ABI, you shouldn't link two programs built with different msan settings. The one exception is libc for which msan adds "interceptors" to make it work.

If you write your own code which you want to integrate with msan by reporting an error where msan normally wouldn't (say, in a function which makes a copy but you know the data needs to be initialized) then you can use __msan_check_mem_is_initialized from the msan_interface.h file: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/include/sanitizer/msan_interface.h